# How handle server errors in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I would like to know what is the way to handle server errors in react. For example, the error 401 and 409 that come to me from the server.

POST http://URL/api/Auth/signIn 401 (Unauthorized)

POST http://URL/api/Auth/signUp 409 (Conflict)

Comment: "Handle" in what sense? If the error is unexpected, show an error message? If relevant, maybe kick the user out to a login screen? This seems a bit vague for this site.

Comment: create a middleware in react, search for interceptor , both axios and fetch have middlewares/interceptor

Comment: The question is too generic.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a try  catch , on the catch you use useState to set the value of the errors on a variable and show it on the html if the error is different to undefined

like this

```
try{
...
} catch {(error) => this.setState({err: error})}
```

```
{(this.state.err!== undefined) ? this.state.error ! ''}
```